# DocuSign Request Signature from API

Tags: asp.net-web-api, docusignapi, e-signature, docusign-sdk

We Have a Document Management System(DMS) which is .Net WebAPI Used to share Documents Between our employees,and stores the documents in our DB Can we implemet the workflows
1)
A authorised admin uploads a document into the API with names and Emails of signers and send it to them for signing and get the signed document and store it in our DB
through docusign

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a DocuSign envelope using the DocuSign eSignature API where you can specify signers ("recipients"), documents and fields ("tabs") that recipients need to take action on in those documents.

This is the API reference for the API call to create an envelope: https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/envelopes/envelopes/create/

This is an example How-To guide for a simple signature request using the various SDKs (including C#):
https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/how-to/request-signature-email-remote/

You are able to download documents from DocuSign through the API as well: https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/envelopes/envelopedocuments/get/

This is an example How-To guide for downloading envelope documents using the SDKs: https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/how-to/download-envelope-documents/

You can download the Quickstart example project in a language of your preference, which includes those How-To examples if you wanted to test it out: https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/quickstart/

Or you can check out the Sample Apps here to see some example use cases: https://developers.docusign.com/sample-apps/

There are generally a few more concepts/terminology to be familiar with when working with the DocuSign APIs (such as how to authenticate). You can check out this page which has links to some of these general topics: https://developers.docusign.com/platform/